# Executing typescript file gives SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, typescript

I just started learning TypeScript and I don't have any prior knowledge of JavaScript. I know both are kind of similar. I am facing an issue at runtime, not compile time. Perhaps I am misusing the syntax? The video tutorial I am currently learning from is pretty old. Maybe th syntax has changed in the meantime. Can you please tell me, what the problem is with the code? I would be thankful for typescript best practices and guides.

Code:

```
class Point{
    
   x: number;
   y: number;
    
    draw(){
        console.log('X ' + this.x + ',Y ' + this.y);
    }

    GetDistance(another: Point){
        //....
    }

}

let p = new Point();
p.draw();
```

Console output:

```
Error: x: number;

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

Comment: you should post the complete code and error here, for future ref. just in case the image on the image hosting platform is removed

Comment: Also if you think the syntax has changed, why aren't you looking at the official docs?

Comment: ok...thank you very much for the advise...well actually i found out the solution for above problem...so how can i close this post

Comment: or should i remove the post??

Comment: i'd recommend editing your post to include the code and the error, then posting the solution as the answer so that it can be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

So i was able to solve above problem. Actually i was trying to load TypeSciprt file that is .ts file rather than .js file. I got to know When we write TypeScript files we can compile them with the compiler (tsc) and it outputs .js file which we can load in the browser nodejs